# RxJS: skip conditional mergeMap

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs

I have such service method:

```
updateUser(article) {
        this.httpClient
            .put(`articles/${article.id}`, article)
            .pipe(
                map(res => res.response),
                mergeMap(updatedArticle =>
                    this.articlesTagsAPI.someMethod(updatedArticle.id).pipe(
                        map(tags => ({ ...updatedArticle, tags })),
                        article.articleType === 'news'
                            ? mergeMap(() =>
                                  this.articlesTagsAPI.someOtherMethod(updatedArticle.id, article.tags).pipe(
                                      map(() => {
                                          return {
                                              ...updatedArticle,
                                              tags: article.tags
                                          };
                                      })
                                  )
                              )
                            : null
                    )
                )
            );
}
```

as you can see - I'm trying to add a conditional `mergeMap` (if condition -> call else one more method)
is it possible to do somehow?

because returning null - isn't the best idea

something like this should happen if conditional is invalid:

```
updateUser(article) {
            this.httpClient
                .put(`articles/${article.id}`, article)
                .pipe(
                    map(res => res.response),
                    mergeMap(updatedArticle =>
                        this.articlesTagsAPI.someMethod(updatedArticle.id).pipe(
                            map(tags => ({ ...updatedArticle, tags }))
                        )
                    )
                );
    }
```

Comment: Not really related, but you could reduce nesting a lot here. For example, just return `this.articlesTagsAPI.someMethod(updatedArticle.id);` and then put the map in the same pipe. You could then do the same for `someOtherMethod` (and using `empty()` if the condition is false as `rguerin` showed. I personally think it would look a lot better and cleaner, but I guess that's just up to taste.

Comment: @ShamPooSham can you provide a code sample?

Comment: If you create a stackblitz with your example first I could modify it, but I don't really have time to do one from scratch right now

Comment: no need in this anymore :) please check my comments below @rguerin answer

Answer (score 2):

As stated in this very useful [article](https://medium.com/@paynoattn/3-common-mistakes-i-see-people-use-in-rx-and-the-observable-pattern-ba55fee3d031), the proper way of doing this would be to add the `of` instruction to always return an Observable its value inside your final subscribe.

Try this:

```
updateUser(article) {

    this.httpClient
        .put(`articles/${article.id}`, article)
        .pipe(
            map(res => res.response),
            mergeMap(updatedArticle =>
                this.articlesTagsAPI.someMethod(updatedArticle.id).pipe(
                    map(tags => ({ ...updatedArticle, tags })),
                    article.articleType === 'news'
                        ? mergeMap(() =>
                                this.articlesTagsAPI.someOtherMethod(updatedArticle.id, article.tags).pipe(
                                    map(() => {
                                        return {
                                            ...updatedArticle,
                                            tags: article.tags
                                        };
                                    })
                                )
                            )
                        : of(null)
                )
            )
        );
}
```

Comment: also not sure why you added `of`.  the main idea: if condition is wrong - we should act like there is no `mergeMap(() => this.articlesTagsAPI.someOthe` at all (the last line is `map(tags => ({ ...updatedArticle, tags }))`)

Comment: with `empty()` my `@effect` is failing

Comment: You can remove the of, sorry I misunderstood your map with a mergeMap. The empty() might be crashing your code because you have several articles and it make the observable complete to soon. Just try returning of(null) instead of null and check the value in your subscribe (I updated my first port).

Comment: it should not return null at all :)) it just has to return prev map data (not sure if I explain it in a proper way, just check my updated question please)

Comment: The thing is an Observable is kept alive until it completes so returning an observable of null is not that bad :) Another solution would be to stop right before your check on article type and subscribe it somewhere else. But you would be subscribing the "someOtherMethod" inside a subscribe which is not a good practice.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

updateUser(article) {

```
  this.httpClient
        .put(`articles/${article.id}`, article)
        
       .pipe(
            map(res => res.response),
            

                mergeMap(() =>       
                 this.articlesTagsAPI.someOtherMethod(updatedArticle.id, 
                           article.tags).pipe(
                                  map(() => {
                                     if(article.articleType === 'news'){
                                      return {
                                          ...updatedArticle,
                                          tags: article.tags
                                      };
                                     }else{ return of([])}
                                  })
                              )
                          )
                        
                )
            )
        );
```

}